# Can't run PostgreSQL locally

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I am working to run PostgreSQL is running locally but I cannot connect.
I installed postgress using brew, then I downloaded http://postgresapp.com

When I try to create a database

> createdb: could not connect to database postgres: could not connect to
>   server: Permission denied     Is the server running locally and accepting
>     connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

I tried to troubleshot this by using :

```
sudo sysctl -w kern.sysv.shmall=65536
sudo sysctl -w kern.sysv.shmmax=16777216
```

But nothing work out.

Any ideas how to solve this

Comment: Don't know about mac but postgres is not running. You have to start the postgres service before doing anything

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed postgresql with brew there's one `createdb` that comes with it and that will connect to brew's postgresql.

Then if you have also installed Postgres.app there's another `createdb` at a different location that will connect to Postgres.app's postgresql.

Since OS X also ships with its own `createdb` in `/usr/bin`, that's a third `createdb` that expects to connect to Apple's postgresql, which is not running unless it's OS X Server Edition. According to the error message, this is the one that you're trying to use and which fails.

The solution is to use the `createdb` command that comes with the PostgreSQL you're actually running. Locate its directory and type the full path of `createdb`, as in `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/createdb`, and/or change your `$PATH` as suggested in [postgresapp's doc](http://postgresapp.com/documentation).

This is a common problem for PostgreSQL on Mac OS X due the existence of many concurrent packages and of client-side programs pre-installed by Apple.

Comment: Do you mean by changing the path in .profile, adding this line PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"

Answer (score 1):

Manually:

create the directory where you want the database files to be:

```
mkdir /postgres_data

chown postgres /postgres_data
```

then initialize the directory:

```
initdb /postgres_data --encoding=UTF8
```

start the database engine:

```
pg_ctl -D /postgres_data start
```

Now you can create your database:

```
createdb test
```

Comment: I got this error message when I try to initdb : 
Data page checksums are disabled.

fixing permissions on existing directory /postgres_data ... initdb: could not change permissions of directory "/postgres_data": Operation not permitted

Comment: Try executing the command as the postgres user `su postgres`

Comment: It says that "-bash: initdb: command not found"