# How to uninstall PostgreSQL (and pgAdmin3) from OSX Sierra?

Tags: postgresql, installation, pgadmin, mac-os-x

I've been having some [difficulty getting up and running](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/159721/new-install-and-admin-establishing-postgresql-password) with PostgreSQL. Having uninstalled PostgreSQL with `brew uninstall postgresql` and [uninstalled/removed Postgres.app](https://postgresapp.com/documentation/install.html) I re-installed Postgresql.app. When initializing the .app I was still getting this error message:

[image: Postgres.app Error Message]

Per [Postgresql.app's documentation](http://postgresapp.com/documentation/remove.html), I looked at my Activity Monitor and saw nothing named postgres or postmaster:

[image: Activity Monitor]

I found [this helpful answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/57027/114032) and after `sudo find / -iname createdb` discovered I had a `createdb` file living in `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin/createdb` who contents
 include "[pgAdmin3.app](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/macos.php)" which is no longer supported. (I am presuming I installed it when I first started looking into PostgreSQL and wasn't really thinking... whoops!) I also searched for `pg_hba.conf` files and found I have a postgres directory in my `usr` dir: `/usr/local/var/postgres/pg_hba.conf`

Is removing the Library's folder (`/Library/PostgreSQL/`) adequate for a complete uninstallation of pgAdmin3, or are there other files and directories to remove? For example, should I also delete `/usr/local/var/postgres/`? Any advice is greatly appreciated, thank you.

NOTE:
per [pgAdmin3's uninstall site](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/45B08CE1.3010207@postgresql.org), `ls -al /Applications | grep pgAdmin` returns nothing.

per [this similar question on another SE site](https://superuser.com/questions/720014/how-can-i-completely-uninstall-pgadmin3-from-os-x),  `sudo find / -iname .pg*` reveals nothing. Also, per [the answer to that question](https://superuser.com/a/720415/630402), `~/Library/Preferences/` does not contain:
org.postgresql.pgadmin.plist.lockfile
org.postgresql.pgadmin.plist
pgadmin3 Preferences

per [the comments in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8038311/5225057) it looks like I should remove the `/usr/local/var/postgres/` directory manually. And from [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8037729/5225057), I also invoked `sudo find / -name "*postgres*"` and got a whole bunch of listings. Of note, I see that [BlackMagic's DaVinci Resolve](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/davinciresolve) is using a PostgreSQL server. The install timestamp of pgAdmin3 is the same as when I installed Resolve... ? Not sure what I need to do.

[This forum conversation](https://forum.blackmagicdesign.com/viewtopic.php?t=37603) sheds some light on Resolve's PostgreSQL server removal.

UPDATE: per comments, when I launch Activity Monitor as admin:

`sudo "/Applications/Utilities/Activity Monitor.app/Contents/MacOS/Activity Monitor"`

...I see these processes associated with user:postgres
[image: Activity Monitor, active postgres processes]

Should I quit these processes before deleting the contents of `/Library/Postgres/...` and other associated files like:
`/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.edb.launchd.postgresql-9.5.plist`

```
/Library/Application Support/Blackmagic Design/DaVinci Resolve/Prereqs/config_postgres.sh
/Library/Application Support/Blackmagic Design/DaVinci Resolve/Prereqs/install_postgres.sh
/Library/Application Support/Blackmagic Design/DaVinci Resolve/Prereqs/postgresql.zip
/Library/Application Support/Blackmagic Design/DaVinci Resolve/Prereqs/upgrade_postgres.sh
```

&

```
/private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/groups/_postgres.plist
/private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/_postgres.plist
/private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/postgres.plist
/private/var/folders/gv/jzhl4n_j2gz6_hjvq4f2xq9h0000gn/C/com.postgresapp.Postgres2
/private/var/folders/gv/jzhl4n_j2gz6_hjvq4f2xq9h0000gn/C/com.postgresapp.Postgres2MenuHelper
```

&

```
/Users/<user_name>/Library/LaunchAgents/com.postgresapp.Postgres2LoginHelper.plist
/Users/<user_name>/Library/Logs/Homebrew/postgresql
/Users/<user_name>/Library/Preferences/com.postgresapp.Postgres2.plist
/Users/<user_name>/Library/Preferences/com.postgresapp.Postgres2MenuHelper.plist
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Aliases/postgres
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/check_postgres.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/postgres-xc.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/postgresql.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/postgrest.rb
/usr/local/var/homebrew/locks/postgresql.brewing
/usr/local/var/postgres
/usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.auto.conf
/usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.conf
```

Maybe I can leave the Homebrew dir/files?

Note: found these with `sudo find / -name "*postgres*"`

Also [per this github blog](https://gist.github.com/Atlas7/b1a40a2ffd85728b33e7), should I "Restore shared memory settings" with `sudo rm /etc/sysctl.conf`

Comment: pgAdminIII _is not_ the tool using the 5432 port. pgAdmin is a _client_ application, not a _server_ listening on port 5432. Most probably you still have one PostgreSQL installation, and it is running. When checking _activity monitor_, make sure you're watching _all processes_ (i.e. include system processes) and not just the ones corresponding to you. From your picture, it looks like you're just checking "My processes". The `postgres` or `postmaster` processes are normally run by the _postgres_ user.

Comment: @joanolo thank you - you are correct. Looking at "All Processes" there are in fact, seven postgres processes running. How do I get rid of them??

Comment: That's a really tough question, because it depends completely on how you installed them in the first place (_source code copilation + make + make install_ does one thing; _brew install_ does another one; the installers from _BigSQL_ and _EDB_ yet another, and Postgres.app...). First step: how did you installed it, second step: look for documentation about how to uninstall it. If you find nothing, check at least Activity Monitor, Open Files and Ports, and see _where_ are your executables and data.

Comment: @joanolo looks like it got installed with another piece of software - Resolve, the video editing/color grading software from BlackMagic (see note in Q?) So I guess my question is, can my PostgreSQL needs co-exist with this install of pgAdmin3...?

Comment: pgAdmin can coexist with all other tools. And you can have several versions of PostgreSQL installed (or several instances of the same version of PostgreSQL), as far as they don't all try to use the same port. You can configure Postgres.app to use port 5433, for instance. The port setting for a certain PostgreSQL installation is specified in the `postgresql.conf` file of that installation. If you use Postgres.app, you have a `preferences` menu where you can chosse (or check) the folder of this file.

Comment: @joanolo, I do not get the "Open Files and Ports" menu tab option when I double click on the postgres processes or their parents. Can you advise? Apologies, I am very new to DB Admin and I really appreciate your explanation of the basics!

Comment: You need to start "Activity Monitor" as "root", that is, open a Terminal and type `sudo "/Applications/Utilities/Activity Monitor.app/Contents/MacOS/Activity Monitor"`. From this point on, you will be able to "see everything" from Activity Monitor. [And you'll see that the menu bar is _greyish_]

Comment: @joanolo mind = blown... I had no idea like in windows you could run apps "as admin"... :) Thank you. Looks like `/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432` is being used by the pgAdmin3 installed with Resolve.

Comment: Check http://forum.blackmagicdesign.com/viewtopic.php?t=37603, changing version as needed.

Comment: @joanolo much obliged - I am going to first see if I can use them concurrently prior to deleting the install from Resolve... I suppose I could also use Resolves uninstaller to wipe my system clean and do what I need to with PostgreSQL to make sure it works... I found that thread at BlackMagics forum earlier and have since registered there to post a related question :) Thank you for your help, I'll try and salvage this post so it is answerable to SE standards.

Comment: @joanolo, updated the post with specifics regarding what to remove. Should I kill the postgres processes prior to removal? Thanks!

Comment: If you don't care about the info inside of those databases, kill them. Otherwise, best way: delete /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.edb.**launchd**.postgresql-9.5.plist and restart your computer. This way, the process won't launch. You can delete anything after backing up whatever you think might interest you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, turns out I had pgAdmin3 installed by DaVinci Resolve 12.5.4's installer and their uninstaller didn't get rid of all the components it installed.

I deleted this file: `/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.edb.launchd.postgresql-9.5.plist` and was able to reboot without the postgres processes launching - note to use Activity Monitor as admin and displaying "All Processes"
`sudo "/Applications/Utilities/Activity Monitor.app/Contents/MacOS/Activity Monitor"`

I then deleted the entire contents of:
`/Library/PostgreSQL/...`
`/usr/local/var/postgres/...`
`/Library/Application Support/Blackmagic Design/...`

and other non rbenv & homebrew "postgres" files (tho I did nuke the homebrew postgres log) I found using `sudo find / -name "*postgres*"`

I've seen a couple "uninstalling" posts, and [this one recommended using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037729/completely-uninstall-postgresql-9-0-4-from-mac-osx-lion)
`sudo rm /etc/sysctl.conf`
but I don't think it applies to OSX Sierra's install of pgAdmin3 components from the DaVinci Resolve installer.